# In a shared PowerPoint presentation (not screen), how do you play a video?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-teams

I am sharing a presentation by selecting a specific PPTX file and clicking through it. It all plays nice, animations and all, until I get to a slide with a video. The video should play on click, but it doesn't and apparantely, clicking play in the video player inside the slide plays the video only for me and all the attendees have to manually click it to start it.

It seems to me that uploading a presentation to Teams has the most sense in this case - when you've got a video in it and want to avoid laggy playback that you naturally get when sharing your screen.

Is it possible to make the video inside an uploaded presentation play for everyone without forcing them to manualy click it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the answers from this question [Sharing a ppt with an embedded video in a Teams meeting](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/sharing-a-ppt-with-an-embedded-video-in-a-teams/e18bd2ab-ed37-474e-aba3-e2c6fd5e0a07) from Microsoft forums, you can try:

Method 1:

> it’s a normal behavior if you share the PowerPoint file directly. As a workaround, you can share your desktop so that you can play the video for all the students at the same time. By the way, remember to select Include system audio when selecting Share in your meeting controls so that the students would hear the audio

So, instead of sharing the presentation only, you will have to share the whole screen to allow others to also view it.

Method 2:

> chose the option to share "window" and then chose the powerpoint presentation, rather than just Powerpoint, we were able to make it work properly.  This didn't share the rest of the screen, so participants still were only able to see the Powerpoint screen and when we got to the video it played perfectly.    It did show the powerpoint screen in full at first though, but as soon as we went to presentation mode, it only showed the presentation.

Method 3:

> If you set the video to start playing on opening of the slide (i.e. select the animation and select "With Previous" then when you navigate to the slide then the video will start playing for everyone who is viewing the presentation. This stops the problem where everyone has to click play seperately.

Comment: Many thanks. I can confirm that setting the video to start playing automatically does solve the issue for me.